# Which method can I use which will be called every time a prop on a component changes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, render, vue-component

I am new to Vue. I am passing props to a child component and when the props change, I am using `watch` to catch the changes and assign them to `this.query`. I am able to log this change in watch and it is working. The prop value is changing on the page but mounted is not being called again, it is only being called once when the component is rendered for the first time,. I want to be able to do a fetch each time these props change.

I have tried to play around with `updated` and `beforeUpdate` but I am unable to log the props there and so don't know where I can fetch the data every time they change.

```js
<template>
  <div class="movie-list">
    <h1>{{ query }}</h1> 
    //At the moment I am just rendering the query which is changing as the prop changes but I want to be able to render movies incrementally from a fetch in mounted() as this.query changes
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  props: ['query'],
  name: 'SearchedMovies',
  data: function () {
    return {
      movies: []
    }
  },
  watch: {
    query: function(newVal){
      this.query = newVal
      console.log('query in watch', this.query); 
      //this is logging each time it changes
    }
  },
  updated () {
    console.log('query in updated', this.query);
    //this is not logging
  },
  beforeUpdate () {
    console.log('query in beforeUpdate', this.query);
    //this is not logging
  },
  mounted () {
    console.log('this is the query in SearchedMovies', this.query);
    //this is logging once when the component first renders
    //I want to be able to do a fetch here each time this.query changes and save the results to this.movies.
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Don't have an answer to why updated isn't being called there, but normally mounted is called, for example, if the parent has a v-if condition on the component and that condition changes from false to true (causing a re-mount). Updated whenever something you see in the dom changes, e.g. when a prop that is being displayed in the template updates. AfaIk updated *should* work here since the DOM (I assume) changes due to `{{ query }}`. On the other hand updated is usually about DOM and it seems this is more about the state and data, so I recommend you react to prop changes in the watcher itself.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I couldn't work out why updated wasn't being called. Anyway, I'll do it in the watcher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `watch` will be called any time the `query` prop changes. You are assigning the new value — which is already in the `query` prop — back to the `query` prop, which is a bad idea, because you should not modify props.

Just put your `fetch` inside the `watch` callback.

Comment: Thanks, Don't know why I didn't think of that!